# Consuming a SOAP API in nestjs using nest-soap

Tags: node.js, authentication, soap, nestjs

I want to create a SOAP client in my nestJs application to consume the API.

Using the nest-soap npm package I followed the documentation and ended up doing the following:

```
 import { SoapModule, } from 'nestjs-soap';

@Module({
 imports: [
   SoapModule.forRoot({
    clientName: 'MY_SOAP_CLIENT',
    uri: "https://my-WSDL-URL",
    auth: {
      username: "myUsername",
      password: "myPassword",
    },
  }),
],
controllers: [AppController],
providers: [AppService],
})
```

When starting the server i get `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials`

This is weird because I can do a valid request using Postman AND also manage to do a successful API call by just using the npm `soap` package.

However I'd like to use the official nest-soap package to have less overhead in my application.

I am not even calling the API here, but since the WSDL file already needs auth, I guess this is where it fails.

with the `soap` package additionally to adding autth to `wsdl_headers` I had to add auth to `http-headers` aswell. I assumed the package does this for me internally, and the docs dont show anything else regarding this.

Comment: nestjs-soap isn't an official package. Do you still have that problem?

Comment: Hello. Internally, nestjs-soap uses soap https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#basicauthsecurity to set credentials. If you're still having this problem, please create a issue on the nestjs-soap repository (https://github.com/lehh/nestjs-soap/issues) with more details about how it's working only with the soap package.